# How to init db in Peewee?

Tags: python, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I'm new in Flask stack. I need to run some project. I created virtualenv and installed all **requirements**:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Login==0.3.1
Flask-Testing==0.4.2
Flask-WTF==0.12
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
WTForms==2.0.2
Werkzeug==0.10.4
argparse==1.2.1
flask-peewee==0.6.6
funcsigs==0.4
itsdangerous==0.24
mock==1.3.0
nose==1.3.7
pbr==1.8.0
peewee==2.6.4
psycopg2==2.6.1
requests==2.7.0
six==1.9.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
wtf-peewee==0.2.3
```

Also I has **runserver.py** script which starts a project:

```
from myproject import create_app
app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Now I want to init db from **models.py**:

```
from peewee import Model, CharField, IntegerField, DateTimeField, DecimalField, TextField, datetime as peewee_datetime
from playhouse.pool import PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase

from .config import BaseConfig


db = PooledPostgresqlExtDatabase(**BaseConfig.DATABASE)
db.commit_select = True
db.autorollback = True


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

    def save(self, **kwds):
        with db.transaction():
            Model.save(self, **kwds)


class Payment(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "payments"

    card_number = CharField()
    amount = DecimalField()
    ....


def init_db():
    try:
        db.connect()
        map(lambda l: db.drop_table(l, True), (Payment,))
        print "tables dropped"
        map(lambda l: db.create_table(l, True), (Payment,))
        print "tables created"
    except:
        db.rollback()
        raise
```

How can I create tables? Is Peewee has something like Django command "*python manage.py migrate*"?
And how to run python shell inside a project like "*python manage.py shell*" in Django?

Comment: use https://github.com/klen/peewee_migrate

Comment: **Anubhav Agarwal**, peewee_migrate not listed in requirements. I need to do it in this stack.

Comment: ОК, I got it. Inside shell I imported init_db() from models.py and run it. No migrations needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.create_tables([Table1, Table2, Table3])
```

Docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#creating-model-tables